# How to finalize a Windows Store App project meant for just one end user?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-store

In the upcoming month or so I will be finishing a Windows Store App project that I was hired to complete for a company that will be using it on a Surface Pro tablet running Windows 8.1 they own as part of a kiosk at their building.

They requested that the app be built for them only.. that it doesn't need to be obtained from the app store where anybody can buy/download it. I am not sure how to finalize this project such that they have what they need to install the app on their device, reinstall it if they accidentally remove it, etc if it does not pass intermediately through the app store.

Is anybody familiar with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sideloading. It's very easy and you don't need any servers or internal stores. [Sideloading WIndows Store Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To circumvent the Windows Store, I believe you need Windows 8.1 Enterprise on the client and Server 2012 R2 to host an internal "store" to distribute the app from via Group Policy.

Comment: See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx